# Extract data from an object from lidar data in r

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I am trying segementation of trees using lidr. I need to count how many points are segemented in each tree. i have a las variable which has an attribute treeID. Using filterpoi i can get individual tree id and see how many points are there. i want to extract the points and create a list for all tree id. My idea is to loop through the treeID and get points for each id. But i cannot seem to extract the points individually . When i print the variable las i get some information i only need the "points". How can i extract this

```
las <-segment_trees(las, algo) # segment point cloud


las <- filter_poi(las, treeID == 1)

> las
class        : LAS (v1.4 format 6)
memory       : 86.8 Kb 
extent       : 368194, 368203.5, 5807536, 5807544 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.  : WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N 
area         : 67.9 m²
points       : 1.1 thousand points
density      : 16.11 points/m²
density      : 9.96 pulses/m²
```

Comment: Maybe `las$points`? If not, you can use `View(las)` and try to identify the name of the element that storage the points info, and then use that name to access the info.

Comment: las$points gives me null. I found if i print the header Num. of points record shows the data which i want but it also gives me null when i use the code you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the `data.table`

```r
las@data[, length(X), by = treeID]
```